# Why TextBox Cleared after submit reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass data from one component to another. but it has no parent child relation and it is independent from each other. i am able to set the state but problem is after clicking enter my text data get cleared. not sure why,

```
export class EmpSearch extends React.Component {
    // Not needed anymore as state going to Redux and not local component state
/*
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Empnumber: ''
    };
    }
*/
 EmpSearch = (e) => {    
if (e.key === 'Enter') {
  browserHistory.push('/Emp/' + e.target.value); 
}
}

updateEmpNumber(e) {

     this.props.dispatch({
            type: 'UPDATE_EMP_NUMBER',
            payload: e.target.value
        });
}

render() {
return (
    <div className="row">
    <form>
        <div className="form-group">
        <label htmlFor="Empnumber">Emp Number</label>
        <input type="text" className="form-control" id="Empnumber" placeholder="Emp Number" value={this.props.Empnumber} onChange={this.updateEmpNumber.bind(this)} onKeyPress={this.EmpSearch}/>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
);
}
 }
 function mapStateToProps(state){
return {
    Empnumber: state.Empnumber
}
}

 export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EmpSearch);
```

Comment: So when you click 'enter' your data is cleared? Or whenever you try to type something into the input box?

Comment: When I click 'enter' value cleared..

Answer (score 0):

`browserHistory.push('/Emp/' + e.target.value);` is probably causing your component to be unmounted and remounted.
You say the value is stored in the redux state, but I can't see where you update the redux state.

Comment: Value is stored in redux and for you i have updated the code above. so if browserhistory.push has problem then what should i use instead of this?

Comment: Ok I see. Not sure what kind of race condition happens here.
Wouldn't it be easier to use `<input type="search" onChange={...} />` ? the Enter key will trigger the form submit event.